# Haskell sendAll message to socket client results in: `Exception: Network.Socket.sendBuf: invalid argument (Transport endpoint is not connected)`

Tags: haskell, unix-socket

I'm running into an error of `*** Exception: Network.Socket.sendBuf: invalid argument (Transport endpoint is not connected)` when calling `Network.Socket.ByteString.sendAll` ([hackage docs - sendall](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-3.1.1.1/docs/Network-Socket-ByteString.html#v:sendAll)) from the socket server (to send to the socket client).

I'm not sure why I get this error? Seems I can only send the data one way?

I also run into the same error when using netcat, instead of the Haskell client:

```
echo 'test' | nc  -N -U /tmp2/test2.soc
```

---

Output from client:

```
*Server Main> main
Hello, Haskell!2
"sent ping....."
```

Output from the server:

```
*Server> serv
"begin"
"Running daemon"
"begin2"
<socket: 13>

"Got message:"
"ping"
"Sending pong...."
*** Exception: Network.Socket.sendBuf: invalid argument (Transport endpoint is not connected)
```

---

Complete project: https://github.com/chrissound/UnixSocketPingPongHaskellTest

Full source code:

client:

```
{-# Language OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import Network.Socket hiding (send)
import Network.Socket.ByteString as NBS
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Hello, Haskell!2"
  withSocketsDo $ do
    soc <- socket AF_UNIX Stream 0
    connect (soc) (SockAddrUnix "/tmp2/test2.soc")
    forever $ do
      send soc ("ping")
      threadDelay $ 1 * 10^6
      print "sent ping....."
      threadDelay $ 1 * 10^6
      msg <- NBS.recv soc 400000
      print msg
      print "got reply to ping...."
    close soc
```

server:

```
{-# Language OverloadedStrings #-}
module Server where

import Network.Socket hiding (send)
import Network.Socket.ByteString as NBS
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad

serv :: IO ()
serv = do
  print "begin"
  print "Running daemon"
  soc <- socket AF_UNIX Stream 0
  bind soc . SockAddrUnix $ "/tmp2/test2.soc"
  listen soc maxListenQueue
  accept soc >>= (\(x,y)-> do
    print "begin2"
    print x
    print y
    forever $ do
      msg <- NBS.recv x 400000
      print "Sending pong...."
      NBS.sendAll soc "ppong"
      print "alll done"

      threadDelay $ 3 * 10^6
      )
```

Comment: Why do you have code after a `forever` block?

Comment: Yeah that probably is useless - left over code when testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending on the listening socket; you probably want to send on the accepted socket instead.

```
  listen soc maxListenQueue
  accept soc >>= (\(x,y)-> do
    ...
    NBS.sendAll soc "ppong"  -- should be   sendAll x "ppong"
```